# Read cookie which is created from NewCookie()

Tags: javascript, cookies

I created a cookie using Newcookie() and I can access it thorough the browser as below. Now I need to read the cookie
[image]

```
    function getCookieValue(cookieName) {
    console.log("=====getCookieValue=======");
    var name = cookieName + "=";
    var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
    console.log("=====ALL cookies======="+cookies);
    if (!cookies) {
        return null;
    }
    console.log("=====cookies.length======="+cookies.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
        var cookie = cookies[i];
        console.log("=====cookies======="+cookies[0]);
        if (cookie.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return cookie.substring(name.length, cookie.length);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

But by using that method I cant read the cookie. Please advice me on this.
Thanks

Comment: Maybe use `.split('; ')` (with the whitespace) instead?

Answer (score 1):

Your function is almost perfect. You just need to change this line:

```
document.cookie.split(';');
```

You can examine the result in the console by running the above statement: you’ll get an Array with all the cookies *but each one of them is preceeded by a whitespace*. That’s why the comparison

```
if (cookie.indexOf(name) == 0)
```

doesn’t work like expected, because the expected substring doesn’t start at position 0 but at 1.

Therefore, you’ll want to split the list of cookies not by a single semicolon but by a semicolon *and a whitespace*. I’m not sure about *all* the browsers out there, so I think the safest way to do it is with a RegExp that checks for an optional whitespace:

```
document.cookie.split(/;\s?/);
```

Comment: I changed the split as you suggested. But when i'm looking at the console it displays as below. document.cookie.split(/;\s?/) [" "]. document.cookie is also returning a blank array. It means the function is not reading any of the cookies. But I can see the cookies from the browser. :(

Comment: Really? What does `document.cookie` return in the console?

Comment: @Hasanthi That’s impossible… `document.cookie` must return a string, not an array.

Comment: Sorry Xufox. yes you are right. It returns empty string as "" . I dont know why it returns an empty String though I'm having a cookie

Comment: I’ve just tested it by my self with 0, 1 or more cookies. It should all work. Try refreshing the page with `Ctrl` + `F5`, closing the dev tools, opening them again, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this..

```
document.cookie.split(";", -1)
```

Calling String.split(String) returns String.split(String, 0) and that discards trailing empty strings. String.split(String, n) with n < 0 won't discard anything.

For further understanding you can follow javadocs:- [Split docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String,%20int))

Comment: thanks. but document.cookie returns null in my code. I don't know why it is happening. Still I can see the cookie from the browser.

Comment: If possible, could you please share the cookies creation logic

Comment: Or else, check whether httponly flag or secure flag are set or not. If they are true, then they force the cookie to be sent over https. This would not allow javascript to read the cookies..